# VertexAI AutoML Tables evaluation runs fails

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-cloud-automl

While trying to run "Create Evaluation" jobs on a trained Vertex AI AutoML Tables model using the UI Console, the pipeline run fails as shown in the below image:

[image]

Looking at the logs leads to the following error:

```
vertexevaluation.error.error.UserError: Query Failed: the provided prediction_score_column in not in the BQ table. 400 Unrecognized name: prediction at [2:1]
    raise UserError(
  File "/vertexevaluation/shared/bigquery_utils.py", line 77, in query_for_result
    bigquery_utils.query_for_result(bq_project, query_str)
  File "/vertexevaluation/shared/pipeline_arg_parser.py", line 711, in set_default_for_regression_forecasting_bigquery
    prediction_score_column = set_default_for_regression_forecasting_bigquery(
  File "/vertexevaluation/shared/pipeline_arg_parser.py", line 1244, in build_evaluation_config
    return pipeline_arg_parser.build_evaluation_config(argv)
  File "/vertexevaluation/evaluation/evaluation_main.py", line 82, in _get_config_from_args
    eval_config = _get_config_from_args(argv)
  File "/vertexevaluation/evaluation/evaluation_main.py", line 239, in evaluation_run
    evaluation_main.evaluation_run(sys.argv)
  File "/main.py", line 42, in <module>
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

The column titled `prediction_score_column` is expected to be created by the evaluation job itself and is outside the parameters that I provide when submitting the evaluation job.

The error started creeping up after the Pipeline / Component was shifted to `evaluation-automl-tabular-pipeline (1.0.0)` from `vertex-evaluation-automl-tabular-pipeline`.

The prediction results for each row do get saved in a BigQuery table but the pipeline fails and so I cannot see the evaluation results on the UI Console.

Any help around solving this from the GCP Community would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this [Link1](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/tabular-data/tabular-workflows/e2e-automl) and [Link2](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/evaluation/using-model-evaluation) will help you ?

Comment: Nope, these links are not useful as I am doing exactly what's mentioned in the link.

Comment: Can you please check the values for input parameter "prediction\_score\_column",  it should be "predicted\_MAX\_OFFER\_AMOUNT.value" instead of "prediction.value" ?

Comment: @JashShah did you ever find a solution to this? I'm hitting the same problem and as far as i can tell the pipeline itself just appears to be fundamentally broken.

Comment: @dbrianj I was not able to figure this out too. Seems to be a problem from AutoML and Google Cloud Platform's side.